# exceeding range for signed char data type

Tags: c++

If we are on a platform which supports unsigned char data type then, the char range is from 0 to 255.
So,

```
char c = 255 ;
c++ ;
cout << c ; // 0 gets stored to c, which corresponds to null character.
```

But what if we are on a platform which supports signed char (-128 to 127)

```
char d = 127 ;
d++ ;
cout << d ; // will it get the value of -128 or 0 ?
```

If -128, then how can we know the corresponding ASCII symbol for it? (As most websites show symbols for ASCII 0 to 255)
Thank you :)

Comment: I recently got an answer that overflow of signed char is not allowed in C++

Comment: "Not allowed" is incorrect. "Undefined Behaviour" means its result and other effects are *undefined*. That's very different. "Stealing" is not allowed. "What happens when you exceed the numerical range of a signed integer" is not defined.

Comment: Incrementing a *signed* integer past its maximum value is **undefined behavior**.  Since C++ is not a nanny language, the burden of not doing the undefined behavior is upon the shoulders of the programmer.  Only in a fairly limited number of situations is the compiler required to emit a diagnostic (an error message).  To help the programmer, most compilers have additional warnings that can be enabled, and tools like UBSan and ASan to help detect mistakes in the code.

Comment: I once worked on a computer where `char` was range 0 to 511. So `char d = 255; ++d;` resulted in 256.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signed integral types are always a ring of -2^b .. 2^b - 1 since C++20, where b is the number of bits. So, in your second example, if char is 8-bit, you'll likely have `-128` [1]. I say 'likely', because technically signed integer overflow is still an UB and anything might happen, so that's one more reason not to depend on it (see below for further reasons).

If you wanted the range and char is 8-bit, 0 .. 255 [1], you'd need to use `unsigned char`. This is not a platform-dependent feature.

Strictly speaking, there's no such thing as ASCII codes > 127, however, most platforms indeed define character images for 0..255. In that case, the character printed is as-if you'd reinterpret the `char` to `unsigned char`. So `-1` -> `255`, `-2` -> `254`, etc., as long as `char` is 8 bits.

Strictly speaking, character range is not necessarily 8 bits; there are platforms with different char size, e.g. 9 bits used to be very common, so you souldn't depend on it at all.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I not correctly understand this answer or it's wrong, but the behavior for `a + 1` is not defined for a `char a = 127;`. The sentence _"Signed integral types are always a ring"_ seems wrong.

Comment: @jabaa signed integrals are a ring since c++20, however, technically it's still UB. Fixing that in the answer.

Comment: @lorro, thank u for ur answer. how can i know if my compiler has set the char to signed or unsigned by default (i know we can set it manually, but can we know which state the compiler is using by default, if we use simply, char a = 'b' ; )?

Comment: @RamanKumar You might use `std::numeric_limits<char>::min` or `std::numeric_limits<char>::lowest` or `std::numeric_limits<char>::max`

Answer (score 0):

unsigned integer (and as such, the `unsigned char` is an integer type) overflow is well-defined; your `c == 0`.

But for (`signed`) `char`  §5 [expr]/p4:

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined.

So, `d` might be anything. -128, 0, 13, 255.

> if -128, then how can we know the corresponding ASCII symbol for it?

ASCII is just an interpretation of code points. There's no interpretation for a negative value. So, this question makes no sense.